# XMLSerialize ignores first element

Tags: java, xml, json

Hey,
I have a simple utility function:

```
    public static String xmlToJson() {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><account id=\"DEV55419669\"></account>";
        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer()
        String result = serializer.read(xml).toString();
        return result;
    }
```

The result is:

```
{"@id":"DEV55419669"}
```

Any ideas why the XMLSerializer "drops" the first element?

p.s. - XMLSerializer is net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.

Thanks,
Udi

Comment: Ha! Got it!
XMLSerializer can be set with setForceTopLevelObject(true) and the rest is simply a magic. Too bad I can't vote up for myself :)

Answer (score 0):

What first element?

If you're refering to the part starting with `<?xml`, then the reason is simple:

It's not an XML element, but the header (formally it's called the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) and is part of the prolog)

Comment: No.. I'm referring to the "account" element.

Comment: I see. That seems to be ignored, because the root element is implicit. Note that you can specify the name of the root element when serializing to XML.

Comment: Nope.. I changed the XML string to: <bla><account id="aa"></account></bla> and it still ignores the first element. This time "bla"... And do you know how do I tell the serializer what's my root element?